# "Error: Could not install package" when Installing iCal.NET from "Manage NuGet Packages" Feature in Visual Studio

Tags: ical-dotnet

I would like to install iCal.NET from "Manage NuGet Packages" feature in Visual Studio 2013. However, I got an error:

> Error: Could not install package 'System.Reflection.TypeExtensions
>   4.1.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5', but the package does not contain
>   any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that
>   framework. For more information, contact the package author

[image]

My project itself uses .NET Framework 4.5:

[image]

But if I download iCal.NET directly from [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Ical.Net), I can set it as reference with no error.

Anyone knows with this issue?

**EDIT**

I just found this discussion: https://github.com/rianjs/ical.net/issues/101

It seems iCal.NET should be able to support .NET 4.5 since Nuget package version 2.2.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

v4 of ical.net supports `net46` and higher, which would be .NET Framework 4.6. One of my dependencies, [`System.Reflection.TypeExtensions`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Reflection.TypeExtensions/), doesn't support framework versions below 4.6, so I can't go lower than that.

You're welcome to continue using v2, which will work, but isn't updated any longer. If this is an application you have full control over, I would suggest targeting .NET 4.6.latest, if you can.

As a general note, the nuget page for any library will tell you what versions of things they depend on if you click the **Dependencies** header. While I was looking at the [ical.net gallery page](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Ical.Net/), I noticed that my dependencies weren't as clear as they could be, so I published a new version (4.1.7) that makes it clearer what they are.

Comment: Ahh, unfortunately I don't have the full control of targeting my project's .NET version. Just out of curiosity, is iCal.NET version 4.0.1.0 the latest one that support .NET 4.5?

Comment: No, all v4 iterations are .NET Standard 1.3, which [require 4.6 or later](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard#net-implementation-support). You can still use v2 if you need to -- it's still pretty good.

Comment: Oh but I have a reference to version 4.0.1 and it has no error. So, I just want to make sure. For .NET 4.5 project, which one is better? 4.0.1 or 2.3.5(latest of v2)?

Comment: If a v4 version works for you, that's the one I would use.